# Parsing filename from text file gives the wrong details

Tags: windows, parsing, loops, batch-file, filenames

Please note I'm new to scripting so please be gentle!

I have a text file called `list.txt` with just one line (for testing), the line is:

> D:\italy\gfm\users\test\avisgfm_1001_1500.txt

My script is:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%1 in (list.txt) do (
    echo %%~1
    echo %%~d1
    echo %%~p1
    echo %%~n1
    echo %%~x1
 )
```

However the result from the script is:

> ´╗┐d:\italy\gfm\users\test\avisgfm_1001_1500.txt
>   C:
>   \PCI\´╗┐d:\italy\gfm\users\test\avisgfm_1001_1500.txt

Any idea whats going on? I'm doing this via a Windows Batch file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The metavariable should be a (case-sensitive) letter.

Numbers refer to parameters to the routine.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) do (
 echo %%~a
```

and so on will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've saved list.txt with some encoding like UTF-8 with byte order mark at the head of file. BAT can process only ASCII text files. Try to create list.txt as simple ASCII text file. Notepad form Windows can do that.

%%1 works fine but it's better to use letter, for example %%i, as in for spec.